# Is there a canonical definition of a line?

Tags: geometry

Normally the definition of a line is either via two points or its slope and y-intercept.  But both methods of defining a line have problems.  With the first one is the problem, that many points are passing through a single line so you can define a line using every pair of them, which mean that a definition method is not unique.  And the second one can't handle lines with slope infinity (like `x=0`).  I searched and thought about it a little bit, but could find anything.

Comment: Well, axiomatisations have their own complications, but I with a brutal simplification of the discussion, I wouldn't say that what you suggest about the first one makes the definition of *the line* ambiguous: if anything, it makes a definition of "*the two points such that a given line is the line passing through them*" ambiguous (which it is).

Comment: The slope and $y$-intercept approach is just a specialisation of the more "true" $$ax+by+c=0$$ equation for a line, which does not have the same impossible-representation-issues. Again, this representation is not unique, though, as multiplying all of $a,b,c$ with the same non-zero constant yields the same line. Or you can go the route of many axiomatic geometries: just don't define lines at all, and instead only use the axioms to declare how they behave.

Comment: @Arthur I want more something like a unique representation you could store in a computer, or so.

Comment: @ErnestBredar But there are more lines than a computer can store

Comment: You can store them in forms that allow a single line to have several representations, you know. There is no law against it.

Comment: @Arthur Of course there isn't (imagine a parliament trying to pass such a law), but that wouldn't feel very elegant.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I don't want to store every line, if I would I could do it in this way: "This means every line."

Comment: BTW, the correct word to use here seems to be "canonical", not "unambiguous". "Unambiguous" means that a bunch of numbers describe precisely one line. "Canonical" means that two lines are the same if and only if the bunch of numbers are the same.

Comment: So you have two choices here: the Plucker coordinates that AUNebulosa describes below look to be elegant, but perhaps not immediately obvious. Or you can take @Arthur's $ax + by + c = 0$ and add the condition that $a^2 + b^2 = 1$ and you're almost there; you just have to deal with the fact that $(a,b,c)$ and $(-a,-b,-c)$ describe the same line, but otherwise it's a good canonicalization.

Answer (score 2):

[Plücker coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pl%C3%BCcker_coordinates#:%7E:text=In%20geometry%2C%20Pl%C3%BCcker%20coordinates%2C%20introduced,3%2Dspace%2C%20P3.) of a line are in my opinion one of the best ways to represent a line. In $\mathbb{P}^2$, a line is represented by $[l_{01}, l_{02}, l_{12}]$, where $(l_{01}, l_{02})$ represent its direction vector and $l_{12}$ is called the moment. Given any point on the line $(p_1,p_2)$, $l_{12}=l_{01}p_2-l_{02}p_1$. Thus, the line equation turns out to be $$l_{02}x-l_{01}y+l_{12}w=0$$.

Comment: Sorry, I think I don't have the needed background, not even the wikipedia article helped me.  What, for example, means "w"?

Comment: $w$ is just another coordinate axis like $x$ and $y$ to include lines at infinity. $w=0$ implies such a line. $w=1$ implies all the other lines described in the other comments with the equation $ax+by+c=0$. Here, the vector $(a,b)$ is nothing but the direction vector of a line perpendicular to the given line and $c$ is the negative of the dot product of the direction vector of the orthogonal $(a,b)$ and a point $(p_1,p_2)$ on the given line, i.e. $c=-(ap_1+bp_2)$.

Comment: So, essentially, you can store the information of a line uniquely with three parameters, its direction vector and the moment that depends on the direction vector and any given point on the line. Hope that helps!

Comment: that means that if I want to restrict me to normal geometry (without infinity) there is again some values without meaning?

Comment: @ErnestBredar- Yes, there are, but that will happen no matter what representation you choose. Otherwise, the space of all lines would be homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$ (or  $\mathbb R^3$), and it's not.

Answer (score 0):

You can unambiguously define a line as a vector space of dimension 1 (the vector you choose for its basis will help describe it uniquely). Of course, depending on the vector space you are working in, some ligns are simply NOT ligns if you go up a dimension ($x=5$ is a plane in $2D$).

Comment: What would be the definition of, say, x=5 or y=3*2x be using this technique?